# Documenting a Database (Specifically Microsoft Access 2003)

Tags: ms-access, database-design, dump

Coming from the world of MySQL, Postgres, MongoDB, Oracle, etc... I've just been given an MS-Access 2003 database with an application inside it; I need to document it.

I'm not worried about the Tables and relationships -- all standard stuff (except for the linked tables to go to outside data sources via ODBC); I'm noting Queries, Macros, Forms, Modules, Reports, and Pages.  I'm not necessarily concerned about the *data*, and although the schema would be nice, it's all the other Microsoft "extras" that MS-Access provides.

At the moment my strategy is to *manually* build a list of each item and copy'n'paste each query and chunk of VB Code.  (ugh)  That's

Then it struck me, perhaps there's an MS-Access wizard who knows a faster way to get MS-Access to dump its guts in a more human readable format.  At the moment, I can't even select more than one item, nor paste it into notepad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for field references within a Microsoft Access "application"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093475/search-for-field-references-within-a-microsoft-access-application)

Comment: having seen that post, inclined to think this is not a duplicate -- what @Parfait shares below appears to be exactly what I need, but want to validate so I can either credit the answer or provide additional information.

Answer (score 1):

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408951/text-search-in-properties-access-objects/6410015#6410015) with a customized VBA routine to export all Access objects as raw texts.

It uses the VBA method `Application.SaveAsText` (an undocumented option).

Conversely, you can use `Application.LoadFromText` to re-create objects from text file exported using `SaveAsText`.